# Using an op amp as a switch for audio (Dual supply +-12V)

Tags: operational-amplifier, solid-state-relay

I'm wondering if the below circuit would be a reliable bipolar analog swtich. I'd like to be able to disable signals from certain circuits and I'd rather not have to bias and normalize the signal in order to use a typical analog switch. What issues might arise and how could they be corrected?  The op amp is a modern rail to rail jfet input device.

Note: cost is of critical concern, I'm trying to keep cost below $2 per complete setup @1000 units, also assume at least a quad channel op amp, need to control all signals at the same time, ie a quad signal from a set of audio inputs and assume another circuit would be used for another set of signals. Signals are line level.

One more edit: voltage input is line level, but I would like the flexibility to go higher if necessary

Edit: The output doesn't need to go high impedance, but it would be better if it did. Assume V_out will be feeding into a resistor of at least 2kOhms before connecting to other parts of the design.

[image: updated circuit]

Comment: YOu should park this question and ask a new one explaining what you are really trying to do, with what, and for how much...

Comment: @Trevor_G okay, I will do that

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72909/discussion-on-question-by-john-evans-using-an-op-amp-as-a-switch-for-audio-dual).

Comment: In one of your comments you mentioned that you want the output to go high impedance when you use the disable signal.  At least one of the answers currently has a suggestion that would leave the output at ground potential through the opamp (low impedance.) Could you verify the need for high impedance, and edit it into the question? If you don't need high impedance, then I have a suggestion for a really cheap circuit.

Comment: @JRE see update, output doesn't need to go high impedance

Comment: Ok.  I'll post an answer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2paA3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Choose package R from 1 to 23 Ohms depending on [avail](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/interface-analog-switches-multiplexers-demultiplexers/747).

Ground could be Vcc/2.

Comment: this is an excellent solution that I have not seen before! Cross talk appears quite low as well, much less than -90db in the audio range

Comment: My, what big resistors you've got!

Comment: It fits the crosstalk and cost budget   ... you're welcome....

Comment: I tested this, as long as it's before the op amp, there's virtually no distortion, very nice solution

Answer (score 6):

Try this one for size: -

[image]

I'm not saying it will exactly suit your application of course but it does provide food for thought.

Alternatively you should be able to use an analogue switch at the output. You say: -

> I'd rather not have to bias and normalize the signal in order to use a
>   typical analog switch

This doesn't really make sense because you power the A-switch like the op-amp with dual supplies like this one for instance: -

[image]

It's a quad package, runs from +/- 15 volt rails and has a control signal that is 3 volt logic compatible. It cost £1.76 at 1500 pieces from Mouser so if you have 4 channels (as implied in comments) then each channel costs £0.44: -

> @Andyaka opa1679, it's a quad channel, there are 4 inputs and I would
>   like to be able to turn them all on or off more or less simultaneously

One quarter section can both disconnect the op-amp output and provide another line where you can connect a pull-down resistor on the output.

Comment: that's a great solution however, it's too expensive

Comment: @JohnEvans, we only know as much about your requirements as you tell us. If you have a cost limit, you need to include that in your question. But also realize, we're not going to do your engineering work for you.

Comment: What JFET op-amp are you using?

Comment: @Andyaka opa1679, it's a quad channel, there are 4 inputs and I would like to be able to turn them all on or off more or less simultaneously

Comment: mainly this is a cost issue

Comment: How much is your crosstalk spec?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 ideally less than -100db but -80db would be the absolute max tolerable

Comment: I wonder how much distortion the switches add?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 your answer addresses this?

Comment: no but the voltage is so small in shunt mode across the switch it's RdsOn does not change, whereas in the series pass, RdsOn does change with input line voltage. (1V rms?) So the R ratio becomes a factor.  www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt612/slyt612.pdf

Comment: Depends on the unstated load.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of biasing the analog signals I think you could bias the digital signals instead.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f24J0c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A CMOS 4066 analog switch with dual supply.*

- J1 to 4 are the analog switches.
- Q1, Q2 and associated resistors perform level shifting of the 0 - 5 V logic to -7 to +7 V logic to drive the chips.
- Someone may be able to refine this. Certainly, if +/-5 V supplies were used and 5 V logic then Q1, R1 and R2 could be omitted if inverted logic is acceptable.

There's an interesting, if dated looking, article on the use of buffered CMOS for this application at [Ant Audio](http://www.ant-audio.co.uk/index.php?cat=post&qry=ant4066) and there's a datasheet for their [ANT4066](http://www.ant-audio.co.uk/4066/ANT4066_datasheet_1_1.pdf) which is rated to +/-30 V. It seems to be a tall hybrid DIL package.

Andy aka's solution is neater as the logic is handled internally.

Comment: It's nice to see that their datasheet does list the distortion figures injected by the switch, seems common to include those figures in digital potentiometers, hopefully it's mostly the N component contributing to the rather high THD+N measurements that they are quoting for lower cost components. Would level shifting like this work for a digital pot?

Comment: I haven't spent any time reading up on digital pots so I can't help there.

Answer (score 1):

Even oldskool circuits like CD4051, CD4052, CD4053 and their modern cousins of the 74HC flavor have an interesting feature: quoting from NXP's 74HC4053...

- Wide analog input voltage range from 5 V to +5 V
- Logic level translation: to enable 5 V logic to communicate with +/-5 V analog signals

They have pins for +5V, -5V and GND, the latter used as reference for the logic levels. The 4066 does not do this, though. And not all 74HC4053 do (I checked several manufacturers, NXP/Toshiba/ON do this but TI does not seem to).

These chips are very inexpensive.

- Crosstalk.

When the switch is off, only the capacitance from input to output remains in circuit. This means the crosstalk spec will depend on the impedance to ground of whatever is after the switch. If the switch feeds a FET input opamp directly (very high input impedance) the tiny amount of current going through the OFF-state capacitance will leak a lot of signal.

The solution is to use 74HC4053 which has SPDT switches, and connect one of the switch poles to ground. So, either the switch lets the signal through into the opamp which is next, or it connects the opamp's input to ground. In the latter case, leakage through the capacitance of the switch that is off is shorted to ground by the switch that is on.

The value you want is "isolation in off-state", fig 17 in this [datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4053.pdf). At 100kHz it is -90dB, but the load resistor after the switch is 600R. If we use the switch as SPDT and short the unused input to GND through the switch resistance of 60 ohms, it will be 10x better, ir. 20dB better. Pretty good.

- Distortion

The switch's ON resistance varies with input voltage. This only matters if current flows through the switch however. For example, in the classic case of a 4066 used as input switch, followed by a volume pot, distortion will depend on the ratio of voltage-dependent variation of ON resistance versus the resistance of the pot. If it feeds an opamp input directly, current will only flow through parasitic capacitances and will thus be tiny. Also notice the shape of the ON resistance vs input voltage curve. It has sharp wiggles about 2V from the rails (high order distortion) but the center part of the curve is smooth (low order distortion). If your signal is +/-2V with +/-5V rails you will avoid the high-order wiggles.

Parasitic capacitances also vary depending on input voltage (as all silicon capacitors do). Since switches are FETs, we're looking at the Cgs+Cgd capacitance, which diverts a bit of the input current into the gates and then into the driver circuit. This creates distortion which increases with a high source impedance, but this is unknown here.

**When comparing switches for distortion and crosstalk, always keep in mind it depends on the load resistor!**

Anyway. If you want cheap, 74HC4053 seems hard to beat.

Also, watch out your rail to rail opamps: if they have dual input stages (necessary for rail to rail input) distortion will increase at high signal levels when one of the two input stages turns off. Also stuff like open loop gain and linearity tends to fall as the output nears the rails. So a bit of headroom won't hurt. Losing 1-2 dB dynamic range isn't that bad if distortion is lower.

**EDIT**

I dug out an old elektor article about a preamp which used CMOS switches. Since distortion comes from voltage-dependent capacitance and ON-resistance, I said I'd make sure no current flows through the switch by putting the opamp directly afterwards, but Elektor uses the opposite method:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpgI9H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When SW1 is closed, the opamp's feedback keeps the voltage on SW1 at zero volts, which suppresses voltage-dependent effects and distortion. When SW1 is open and SW2 closed, the input is shorted for highest off-isolation. Drawback is that input impedance is R2 so depending on your application you might want to choose a rather high value. If the opamp is JFET-input it doesn't have input current noise though, so that makes it less of a problem.

Since you plan on a large fabrication run, I guess the best would be to take the time to prototype both and measure distortion. I'd be interested in the result!

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I may need to change the question as the op amps aren't completely rail to rail but get to within 800mV, I'm planning on using the new opa1679, I read somewhere that it's more or less a drastically improved TL072c, and I would have to agree, it sounds very good. Distortion figures are of critical concern, so it made sense to use an op amp, since an ultralow distortion op amp is much less than some of these analog switches. It's nice to see that there are ways around this.

Comment: See my edit for new stuff ;)

Comment: I've never used OPA1679 but did use OPA1652 which is more expensive (one of the cheapest "high end" opamps). I can confirm it measures and sounds excellent. The datasheets, performance numbers and even the internal schematics look suspiciously similar between the two, which is good news...

Comment: The OPA1652 definitely makes the cut, very similar performance to the opa2604. I don't have any audio sources that necessitate crazy high performance op amps. Even still these chips only sound a little bit better than a TL072c in a proper topology. Though friends have definitely noticed the more airy, sparkly highs which is funny to me since I'm not really a believer in a lot of the op amp lore.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest a circuit that I've seen used before, but not often seen in any discussion or suggested for use.  Maybe it is just complete crap, and that's why it isn't used. :)

The way I saw this implemented actually used an inverting amplifier with a single supply.  I'm going to try and translate it to a non-inverting amplifier with dual supplies.

First, the original circuit (as well as I remember it:)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHGguK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a simple inverting amplifier with a mute function.

When MUTE is low, audio passes as usual.

When MUTE is high, R2 is shorted and the gain goes from 1 down to something very close to 0.

Now, I'll try to make it work with your setup:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUDdne.png)</sup>

That works pretty much the same way, only you need a low for mute instead of a high.

The bad thing is, that for not muted you need the MUTE signal to be at 15V, and for muted you need it at -15V.

Your typical 5V logic circuit won't do that, so you use this to drive the MUTE signal:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnyt7S.png)</sup>

You only need one logic level converter for each group of signals you want to mute.

You only need one transistor and a resistor for each signal you want to mute.

So, each channel only costs you a few cents, and the logic level converter not much more.

The values are only placeholders - I'm sure it'll need tweaking to get it to work.

It does leave you with that low impedance output from the opamp.  You started out wanting basically an open circuit, but have allowed as muting may be OK.  This gets you a mute but not an open circuit.  Maybe it'll do the job.

---

I couldn't begin to tell you if this will cause problems with crosstalk or distortion.

The device that used this mute circuit only had a single signal path, and the signal was already pretty noisy - like about 45dB SNR on a good day.  So, a little bit of noise sneaking in wasn't going to be noticed.  Distortion was also pretty bad (crappy speakers, and other junk in the signal path) so that wasn't a problem either.

Comment: interesting circuit, using the feed back to mute the signal... of course, with all the logic shifting required, it makes me wonder if it's much better than logic shifting up to a dedicated analog switch... Thanks for the post though, definitely a valid solution

Answer (score 0):

Consider 4053 (CD4053 or 74HC4053) 1of2 multiplexer chips which have level shifting circuitry built in for the logic, unlike the 4066/4016.

3 channels in each for about 15 cents. Ordinary ones are fine at +/-5V, there is at least one high-voltage switch.

If you care about distortion pay attention to the variation of resistance with voltage vis-a-vis the load resistance.